# How can I make Firebase Analytics in a React Native app live on the Play Store upload its analytics data?

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-analytics

I’ve written a React Native app for Android and set it up with Firebase analytics.

When I run the app in debug on my hardware Android Pixel 6, it uploads data just fine.

But after I submit to Play Store for internal testing and download and run on same phone, no analytics are uploaed.

Is there some other configuration I have to set?

Answer (score -1):

If your testing on Apple, there is a possibilty that the analytics are disabled when you havent implemented "App Tracking Transparency". Im not sure if this is the reason, just something the docs point out. Heres the [link](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#disable-ad-id-usage-on-ios).

Comment: thanks for that, that may help when I'm firming up the iOS version.